# Why am I getting ENOENT for a path that exists? (aka how did I break my bot)

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a [Discord bot](https://github.com/siliconealien/simpbot11) written in discord.js V12 and hosted on Heroku.  Everything was fine until tonight, I updated the Stacks container (if that's what it's called) from heroku-18 to 20 and then I went on GitHub and closed all my Dependabot alerts.  Now my GitHub environment is active and Heroku says my build succeeded but my bot is offline.  Here's what appears in my logs when I deploy:

> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510461+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at
> Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510461+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510462+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510462+00:00 app[worker.1]:   errno: -2,
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510462+00:00 app[worker.1]:   syscall: 'open',
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510463+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'ENOENT',
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510463+00:00 app[worker.1]:   path:
> '/database/game.json'
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.510463+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.659237+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with
> status 1
>
> 2022-03-30T07:02:38.704186+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from
> up to crashed

This bot is a Choose Your Own Adventure-type game and that's what the database is for.  The file is just empty { } with a space in between.  But it definitely exists, I don't understand why it suddenly can't find it, it was working fine for a long time.  I feel so stupid for even trying to fix all the security problems, like I should have just not touched anything.  Anyway, hopefully someone's got some tips for me, I have no education on this stuff and am just sort of fumbling around online.  Thanks in advance.

**Edited to show what happened when I tried wgumenyuk's tip:**

> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361282+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> /app/node_modules/jsoning/src/jsoning.js:29
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361298+00:00 app[worker.1]:       throw new
> TypeError(
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361299+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ^
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361299+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361300+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Invalid
> database file name. Make sure to provide a valid JSON database
> filename.
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361300+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new Jsoning
> (/app/node_modules/jsoning/src/jsoning.js:29:13)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361301+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at
> Object. (/app/commands/4simp.js:3:16)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361301+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361301+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at
> Object.Module._extensions..js
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361302+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361302+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at
> Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361303+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361303+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361303+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at
> Object. (/app/index.js:16:18)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.361303+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>
> 2022-03-30T16:26:38.585202+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from
> up to crashed

Comment: Have you tried using `__dirname` in your path? (i.e. `path.join(__dirname, "../path/to/database")`)

Comment: I wasn't 100% certain where you meant to do that but I tried!  Edited my post to show the new log because it was too long to comment.  Didn't work but thank you for trying<3